# Почему не работает ajax в django?

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

Форма:

```
<form class="form" action="{% url 'articles:send_comment' article.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <textarea id="text-comment" name="text" required="" placeholder="Напишите свой комментарий..."  cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    <div class="button-form"><button class="btn-form" id="send-comment" type="submit">Отправить</button></div>
                </form>
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
        var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
        $('#send-comment').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'send_comment/',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "text",
          data: {
            'comment-text': $('#text-comment').val(),
          },
          headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken": token,
          },
          success: function(data){
            console.log(1);
          },
          error: function(error){
            console.log(1);
          }
        });
        });

    </script>
```

Views:

```
def send_comment(request, article_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_text = request.POST['comment-text']
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
        article.comment_set.create(comment_text=comment_text)
        return HttpResponse("Success!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a POST")
```

Urls:

```
app_name = 'articles'


urlpatterns = [
        path('<int:article_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),  # Страница с новостью
        path('<int:article_id>/send_comment', views.send_comment, name='send_comment')
    ]
```

Ошибка:

```
KeyError: 'comment-text'
 comment_text = request.POST['comment-text']
```

В этой строке.
Я пытался уже всё сделать даже отправлять через json, но там он присылался пустым. В консоли не выводится 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поменять путь на `path('send_comment', views.send_comment, name='send_comment')`
И соответственно в ajax тоже